# How to CSS style a table such that its width is within [min, max] percent of page width and as wide as necessary?

Tags: css, width, css-tables

How to CSS style a table such that

1. its width is at the most 80% of page width, and,
2. is at the least 50% of the page width, and
3. is as wide as necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `min-width` and `max-width`

```
min-width: 50%;
max-width: 80%;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want both `min-width` and `max-width`:

```
<style type="text/css">
table
{
  min-width: 50%;
  max-width: 80%;
}
</style>
```

This will make the table at least 50% the width of its container. It will grow (if it needs) to a maximum of 80% width of the page.